# Mongo dbs of 5M and 150M webpages is really really slow

Tags: mongodb

I'm storing a collection of webpages in a mongodb, around 150M webpages. Each page of different size. The only transaction I want to do it to retrieve pages using their id (not mongodb default _id). However, it takes really too long time to get results and I didn't manage to retrieve any document yet. However, use `db.collection.findOne()` works perfectly. Hence, I indexed a subset of 5M webpages for testing and repairing. When issue a query against this db `db.collection.find("id":"aw-000")`, it takes 4 minutes or more to get a document.

I tried `db.runCommand({compact: 'collection'})` and `db.runCommand({compact: 'collection'})` m but they didn't help!

When I checked the logs under `var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` (that should contains any query took more than 100ms), I found this:

```
655163:2017-07-16T14:05:37.231+0300 I COMMAND  [ftdc] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 0, after asserts: 0, after connections: 0, after extra_info: 310, after globalLock: 310, after locks: 310, after network: 310, after opcounters: 310, after opcountersRepl: 310, after storageEngine: 310, after tcmalloc: 310, after wiredTiger: 310, at end: 1220 }
```

However, I don't know how to benefit from such logs.

Is there a way to make my db more efficient?

Comment: Do you have an index on `id`?

Comment: Or did you even think of supplying your "own unique value" to `_id`? Because there is nothing that says it "must" contain an `ObjectId`. Of course using this now would involve rewriting the entire collection. But that should be a simple aggregation pipeline with `$project` and `$out`. But it does sound like you basically just forgot to add an index.

Comment: @JohnnyHK what type of index would you suggest for my case where I only need to retrieve documents from db using my own id field. I created actually the unique index for my own id field, but this doesn't improve my queries response time. I read documentation, but they doesn't recommend anything.

Comment: @Neil Lunn if I got you correctly, you mean I don't have to add attributes called id as mongodb has default attribute called _id. For this, I think it depends on the application and data I'm using; in my case I used my own id as it reflects the crawl I have where each webpage has it's own that is used by applications my team had developed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by Neil Lunn in the comments above. I found the easiest solution is to create the db from scratch, while using `_id` as my id field name instead of `"id"`.  `_id` has an index by default and the only type of queries will be issued against this index is retrieving by id.

So, the program (any program that's used to create the index) will insert the object as following:

```
db.collection.insert( { _id: "aw-000", page: "...", .... } )
```

instead of:

```
db.collection.insert( { id: "aw-000", page: "...", .... } )
```